# Roll Up rows in SQL

Tags: sql

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVxwz.png)

I have a table like this and am trying to rollup the rows into one row. Is there a way I can do this in SQL, the only way I can think of is maybe doing a bunch on self joins on the same table

Comment: Use `group by` with `max`... It will result in a single row without the `null` values.

Answer (score 1):

You could `group by` ID, and get the `max()` value of each column.

```
select
    ID,
    max([Date 1]) as [Date 1],
    max([Email 1]) as [Email 1],
    [...]
    max([Email 3]) as [Email 3]
from
    my_table
group by
    ID
```

Comment: Looks good depending on the version of the database - some don't support brackets `[]` when selecting columns.

Comment: @sgeddes Very true. OP didn't tag a database, and I don't think the screenshot is from a real table (the `NULL` values are upper case in some columns, and title case in others), so I just went with the square brackets.